# Getting a unsigned short value using Img.at<cv::vec3???>

Tags: c++, opencv

I'm currently working on an High Dynamic Range algorithm for one of my class. And I've a problem using OpenCV.

I have a 16 bits raw image and I'm trying to display the value in this image using

```
image.at<cv::Vec3s>(y,x)[0];
```

but I'm getting negative values. Also I work with a `CV_16UC3` matrix, so something must be wrong.

Is there a way to get an `unsigned short` value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To read values from a `CV_16UC3` image you should use a `Vec3w`, which is a vector of 3 `unsigned short`:

```
typedef Vec<ushort, 3> Vec3w;
```

---

You can also use a `Mat3w` (aka `Mat_<Vec3w>`) and access values without `.at<Vec3w>`, but only with parenthesis.